# Select a date 7 days after current date in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have input in html like this:

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Collection *" id="m_date" name="m_date" type="date" tabindex="6" required/>
```

I would like to select a date that is more than 7 days from the current date, if I select a date before 7 days from current, it should prompt saying "Wrong date selected"

How do I do that in javascript?

I tried the following:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);

console.log(date);
```

It gives the date correctly. How do I use this to compare if date is 7 after or not and prompt accordingly?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

```
<html>

<body>

<input class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Collection *" id="m_date" name="m_date" type="date" tabindex="6" required/>

</body>

</html>

<script>

let cal = document.body.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0];
cal.onchange = function(e) 
{
    var selectDate = e.target.value
    var startDate = new Date(Date.parse(selectDate));
    console.log(startDate);
    
    var dateAfter7Days = new Date(new Date().getTime()+(7*24*60*60*1000))
    
    console.log("7 days " + dateAfter7Days);

    if (startDate => dateAfter7Days )
    {
        console.log("Allow");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Don't allow");
    }
}

</script>
```

I am getting "Allow" for any date I select.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: If you do what you've did in your example, you can just compare the selected date and make sure that it is not bigger than this `date` object.

Comment: I don't know how to compare dates by the given date and prompt immediately wrong date.

Comment: So you want to get 'Wrong date selected' if a date not in coverage is selected?

Comment: You can compare the date's time, something like this `date.getTime() <= selectedDate.getTime()`. If this condition is true, the selected date is not more than 7 days in the future.

Comment: @jacobkim that is right

Comment: @Titus: Please check my update, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is comparing two date values. If current date - selected date > 7 then it should print prompt. The problem is how to get selected date.

You can get the selected date from the input tag by event value. On changed date, the value get logged.

```js
let cal = document.body.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0];
cal.onchange = function(e) {
console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Collection *" id="m_date" name="m_date" type="date" tabindex="6" required/>
```

Comment: I tried the following but didn't work

let cal = document.body.getElementsByClassName('form-control')[0];
cal.onchange = function(e) 
{
 console.log(e.target.value);
 var selectDate = e.target.value

 var date = new Date();
 date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);

 console.log(date);

 if (selectDate => date)
 {
  console.log("Allow");
 }
 else
 {
  console.log("Don't allow");
 }
}

Comment: @SanjanaNair Seems my explaining isn't good! On if condition the condition should be value of current date - value of selected date >= value of 7 days.

Comment: @SanjanaNair the values of dates should be set of data as number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date();
var next_seven_date = d.getDate()+7;
var current_month = d.getMonth();
current_month++; // month start from 0 then we need to +1
var current_year = d.getFullYear();

var weekDate =(next_seven_date + "/" + current_month + "/" + current_year);

date.setDate(weekDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your problem is to compare dates not creating them I have updated my answer which might hlp you

```
var currentDate= new Date();
currentDate= new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate(),0,0,0)

var idealDifference= (7*24*60*60*1000);

//In your case this date might comes from some date selection user control. Be aware to make the time part of each date to same
var userSelectedDate = new Date(2021, 04, 04,currentDate.getHours(),0,0,0) 

if((userSelectedDate.getTime()-currentDate.getTime())>=idealDifference)
{
    console.log(userSelectedDate, ' is after 7 days from ',currentDate)
}
else
{
    console.log(userSelectedDate, ' is before 7 days from ',currentDate)
}
```

**Note: It is important to unset the time part of both the dates before comparing for this logic to work**

Comment: see the updated answer. Since I am using epoch time for comparison it wont be that accurate to seconds level. but this might be enough for most cases